# How to generate gif in android?

Tags: android

How to generate gif frame by frame, base on a canvas?

I'm writing a chess game, and want to generate a gif file from every move by user. Is there any apis provided by sdk?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately that is not possible with any built-in function. The SDK does not come with the ImageIO class. You can make use of this animated GIF encoder:

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/2D-Graphics-GUI/AnimatedGifEncoder.htm

Comment: Thanks! This class uses java.awt.BufferedImage, but this is unavailable in android sdk

Comment: I see! Give me a moment, I'll do some research for you. Looks like it only uses BufferedImage to get the pixels, which you can also do with Bitmaps in the SDK. Just rework getImagePixels and it should do the trick.